# After installing Ubuntu 13.10 all files are erased

Tags: 13.10, files

I just installed Ubuntu 13.10 by following instructions. But after downloading and installing all updates I can't find my files. All the data it's been formated or deleted. I want to know why did it happen?

Comment: It would be helpful if you showed us what instructions you followed

Comment: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BootFromCD

Comment: also i cant install AMD Radeon 7670 graphics driver

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it was an upgrade, your files should be untouched, unless you picked "Erase disk and install Ubuntu" or "Something else" (and set it up manually to do this) this shouldn't have happened.

Did you maybe use a different username and now have a fresh home folder? Check in /home/ for any other directorys.

If it really is gone (and you happen to have no backup), go boot up a live cd immediately. You may be able to recover files, but using the system and letting it write more to disk increases the chance of your data to be unrecoverable.

Take a look [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DataRecovery).

Comment: also i cant install the graphics driver software. after downloading the file, the file extension is ".run" how could i open or download and install it?

Comment: Typically you'd use a graphics driver offered through the system, check in Software & Update > Additional Drivers if the one you want shows up there to use. If it doesn't, and you know you want that one installed you can open a terminal window where your file is and make the file executable with "chmod +x file.run" and then run it with "sudo ./file.run".

Comment: when i try to execute i get this:command not found

Comment: also i got: driver not supported. i got AMD Radeon HD 7670 DDR3 graphics card in my laptop

Comment: "http://www.thefanclub.co.za/how-to/ubuntu-amd-catalyst-install" i tried this. and after installing and detecting it says driver not supported